# Setting {document: true, query: false} in pre updateOne hook, does not trigger the hook

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to get a `schema.pre("updateOne"...)` hook to work with Mongoose, but I can not figure out what I am doing wrong.

I have a simple schema of a `Department`, it has a `name` and `initials`.

If the name gets updated, I also want to update the initials, so I need both the document and the query in the function, I need the query so that I can create the new initials, and check if they already exist, and only then allow the update, so something like:

```
schema.pre("updateOne", function(next) {
  const query = ???;
  const document = ???;

  document.initials = query.name.substring(0, 4).toUpperCase();

  next();
});
```

I have tried to use the `{ document: true, query: false }`, but that just skips the hook altogether and code in it does not get executed at all, and I still don't have access to both of these.

I am struggling to find any meaningful resources with examples about using the pre/post updateOne hooks.

The way that I initiate the updateOne:

```
await DepartmentModel.updateOne(
  { _id: Types.ObjectId(id) },
  {
    ...departmentUpdateInfo,
  }
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html#notes is pretty clear about "updateOne" is not intended to work on models:

> That's because pre('updateOne') document middleware hooks into Document#updateOne() rather than Query#updateOne().
>
> ```
> schema.pre('updateOne', { document: true, query: false }, function() {
>   console.log('Updating');
> });
> const Model = mongoose.model('Test', schema);
>
> const doc = new Model();
> await doc.updateOne({ $set: { name: 'test' } }); // Prints "Updating"
>
> // Doesn't print "Updating", because `Query#updateOne()` doesn't fire
> // document middleware.
> await Model.updateOne({}, { $set: { name: 'test' } });
> ```

I doubt I can explain it better than in the docs, but when you call `DepartmentModel.updateOne` it is being translated directly to `db.departments.updateOne()` mongodb query. There is no Depratment document in javascript.

For your hook to work you need to load the document first, e.g.

```
let department = await DepartmentModel.findOne(
  { _id: Types.ObjectId(id) }
);
```

Then call the updateOne on **document** level:

```
await department.updateOne(
  {
    ...departmentUpdateInfo,
  }
);
```

Comment: Thanks, now it works, I am new to this, what is the intended use of pre updateOne with a query only? To add more data to it or? And what is the difference between finding the document sending it in (as what I am doing atm) and updating it in there, and getting the query and doing work on the query and it still updates the same document? Can you point me to some resources that might explain this? I cant see the use case for both of these ways of doing it

Comment: UpdateOne on model level is more efficient since you don't need to query and load the document to the nodejs memory. https://mongoosejs.com/docs/  and https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose are the best sources of information. I must admit it's not very well structured so we are trying to fill the gaps here on Stackoverflow.  If the answer solved the problem please consider to accept it.